# How to protect a button in disabled mode?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to disable a button if user doesnt have rights to access it. I am 
                            disabling at Page_Load event

```
 Page_Load() {
      if(!userhasrights) {
           btn.Enabled=false;
      }
 }
```

but after rendering asp.net just sets its disabled property to disabled which
                        a hacker can easily set to 'true' & can access the button. How can i 
                        protect my button in disabled mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot protect the html state of the button, since users can always modify it.

You should have server-side validation when the button is pressed, and return error/warning to users who are not authorized to click on it. You can still user the disable state for usability.

The other solution is not to generate the button when the users are not authorized to click on it. If you really need to have the disabled button, add an image instead of a button.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you do it not at the client side in javascript but at serverside using an *if... else*

In your script it should be something like this

```
if(userHasRights)
{
       // display code for button
}
else
{
       //display appropriate message
}
```

Comment: Button MySexyButton = new Button(); MySexyButton.Text="Only Chosen can click meh"; AnyASP:Panel.Controls.Add or Append(MySexyButton); Just add OnClick Event handler same fasion as .Text property. Better would be to have a ASP:Panel and play with it's Visible state rather programming Button yourself...

Comment: use <%="Here goes your HTML code"%> syntax to output the string

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using button's `Enable` property you should use `Visible` property to make it secure, because if a control's `Visible` property is `false` in that case it will not rendered. So there is no question of hacking.

```
Page_Load() {
      if(!userhasrights) {
           btn.Visible=false;
      }
 }
```

Comment: But this could be easily enabled by user executing a simple JS in his browser. So question of security is not addressed. Instead we have to NOT output the button's HTML code itself

Comment: @footy: if a control's Visible property is false in that case it will not rendered means it will not be available in HTML code try it.

Comment: Yes it wont render and i agree. But why take the risk to put the button there at all? Anyway all this will be pointless if the script doesnt involve some kind of backend checking any way. :)

Comment: As everyone is saying, it is NOT secure to do this in the client side. @Thomas using any inspect tool (firebug, chrome inspector, etc) you can change the visible property. It is NOT safe to do this. Whats the point of leaving the button if it is not rendered? Just don't send it...

Answer (score 0):

As per knowledge and experience security should apply as close as your code need it.

Like just before executing code that required special previledge.